# Problem with removing/animating a YouTube flash video-player container

Tags: jquery, youtube, jquery-1.3, flash

I used the code from the following question to insert a YouTube video into a page: [[How to resize a YouTube player, from thumbnail size to 'normal' size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314662/how-to-resize-a-youtube-player-from-thumbnail-size-to-normal-size)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314662/how-to-resize-a-youtube-player-from-thumbnail-size-to-normal-size).

Given the following html:

```
<dl>
<dt>Thoughts of Sacrament</dt>
<dd><div class="placeholder"><img src="img/H5ZEYFgmfYo.png" id="H5ZEYFgmfYo" /></div><div class="close">x</div><p>There is no purpose to this text, it's just here in order to provide a frame of visual reference while I work upon the code behind this here 'page,' still: I hope you enjoy, uh...looking.</p></dd>
<dt>Sanity falling</dt>
<dd><img src="img/2ieLb3RAblA.png" id="2ieLb3RAblA" /></dd>
</dl>
```

I expected that the following jQuery should remove the `.placeholder` div that contains the YouTube video:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // ...Other code to insert the YouTube...

$("div.close").click(function() {

    $(this).sibling("div").remove();
            // $(this).parent().empty();

});
```

});

Eventually I aim to 'reverse' the original animation and then swap the youtube video for the original `.png`, but I'm having trouble accessing the relevant div. The commented out code works, and empties the parent element, but I just can't seem to access the sibling `.placeholder`.

Any help would be more than appreciated, thanks in advance =)

---

### Update:

So far I've not got much further than before, the current page is over [here](http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/projects/jq&yt_demo.html), and the code from that page is below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>jQuery & YouTube</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!--

    Currently -almost- works
        - unfortunately the 'close' option doesn't care
        if the video's been played or not (and will remove the picture if it's there).
        - the close button also (tries?) to animate the flash object and then drops
        the replacement image in. Looks wrong.

        On updating the page, the image -after closing/removing the video
        is no longer 'clickable'

-->

        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".placeholder img").click(function () {

        var videoID = $(this).attr("id");

        $(this).animate({ 
        width: "445px",
        height: "364px"
        }, 600, function() {

            $(this).replaceWith("<object id=\"" + videoID + "\" class=\"yt\" width=\"425\" height=\"344\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID + "&hl=en&fs=1&color1=0x3a3a3a&color2=0x999999\"></param><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param><param name=\"autoplay\" value=\"1\"></param><param name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"></param><embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID + "&hl=en&fs=1&color1=0x3a3a3a&color2=0x999999\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" width=\"425\" height=\"344\"></embed></object>", function() {$(this).parent().children().find("div .close").toggle()} );
        });
    });

    $("div.close").click(function() {

        var videoID = $(this).parent().find("object").attr("id");

        $(this).parent().children("div .placeholder").animate({
            width: "252px",
            height: "199px"
            }, 600, function() {

                $(this).replaceWith("<div class=\"placeholder\"><img id=\"" + videoID + "\" src=\"img/" + videoID + ".png\" /></div>");
                });
        });

});

        </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="head">

        <div id="branding" title="demo page for jQuery issues.">

            <h1>jQuery and YouTube problems</h1>

            <div id="navigation">

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">videos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">dates</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">

    <dl>
        <dt>Thoughts of Sacrament</dt>
        <dd>
            <div class="placeholder">
                <img src="img/H5ZEYFgmfYo.png" id="H5ZEYFgmfYo" />
            </div>

            <div class="close">x</div>

            <p>There is no purpose to this text, it's just here in order to provide a frame of visual reference while I work upon the code behind this here 'page,' still: I hope you enjoy, uh...looking.</p>
        </dd>

    <dt>Sanity falling</dt>
        <dd>
            <div class="placeholder">
                <img src="img/2ieLb3RAblA.png" id="2ieLb3RAblA" />
            </div>

            <div class="close">x</div>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll notice the over-use of divs (used because I thought -for some reason- it might make navigating the DOM easier: so far as I can tell, it didn't), for which I can only apologise. And I'll make the necessary sacrifice to [Meyer](http://www.meyerweb.com), [Molly](http://www.molly.com) and [Cederholm](http://www.simplebits.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...after some work and lots and lots and, well, *lots* of trial and error and much reference to the jQuery docs and other SO questions to get a feel for what's going on here, I hacked together a particularly dirty means of accessing the sibling `.placeholder` div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// ...Other code to insert the YouTube...

    $("div.close").click(function() {

        var videoID = $(this).parent().find("object").attr("id");

        $(this).parent().children("div .placeholder").replaceWith("<div class=\"placeholder\"><img id=\"" + videoID + "\" src=\"img/" + videoID + ".png\" /></div>");

    });

});

<div id="content">

<dl>
    <dt>Thoughts of Sacrament</dt>
    <dd>
            <div class="placeholder"><img src="img/H5ZEYFgmfYo.png" id="H5ZEYFgmfYo" /></div>
            <div class="close">x</div>
            <p>There is no purpose to this text, it's just here in order to provide a frame of visual reference while I work upon the code behind this here 'page,' still: I hope you enjoy, uh...looking.</p>
        </dd>

    <dt>Sanity falling</dt>
    <dd>
            <img src="img/2ieLb3RAblA.png" id="2ieLb3RAblA" />
        </dd>
</dl>

</div>
```

I had hoped that this would in some way reset the page to its starting position, in order that I could click on the `.png` to enlarge the image and then replace with the video, click on the `.close` div to shrink it back down and then be able to click on the `.png` to enlarge it and insert the YouTube video again.

I don't know why that seemed like a good idea, but it did. Sadly it doesn't work and I have no idea why. I have...a *hunch* it might be to do with the jQuery [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) event/function/thing (I'm *really* new to jQuery), but I don't see how to connect everything together, yet.

I'm going to leave the question open a while longer, since I suspect there are lots of better answers applicable to the question I raised. There's almost have to be, really.

Just for completion's sake, as this is a development of an earlier question I'll post the entire code from the `html` file below, so's anyone coming in can see what I've done and hopefully have an idea of why, if not a better understanding of my decision-process.

The whole code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>in the absence of light | ITAOL</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("img").click(function () {

        var videoID = $(this).attr("id");

        $(this).animate({ 
        width: "445px",
        height: "364px"
        }, 600, function() {

            $(this).replaceWith("<object id=\"" + videoID + "\" class=\"yt\" width=\"425\" height=\"344\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID + "&hl=en&fs=1&color1=0x3a3a3a&color2=0x999999\"></param><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param><param name=\"autoplay\" value=\"1\"></param><param name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"></param><embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID + "&hl=en&fs=1&color1=0x3a3a3a&color2=0x999999\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" width=\"425\" height=\"344\"></embed></object>");
        });
    });

    $("div.close").click(function() {

        var videoID = $(this).parent().find("object").attr("id");

        $(this).parent().children("div .placeholder").replaceWith("<div class=\"placeholder\"><img id=\"" + videoID + "\" src=\"img/" + videoID + ".png\" /></div>");

    });

});

        </script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrap">

    <div id="head">

        <div id="branding" title="In the Absence of Light.">

            <h1 title="In the Absence of Light">In The Absence of Light</h1>

            <div id="navigation">

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">videos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">dates</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="content">

    <dl>
        <dt>Thoughts of Sacrament</dt>
        <dd>
            <div class="placeholder">
                <img src="img/H5ZEYFgmfYo.png" id="H5ZEYFgmfYo" />
            </div>

            <div class="close">x</div>

            <p>There is no purpose to this text, it's just here in order to provide a frame of visual reference while I work upon the code behind this here 'page,' still: I hope you enjoy, uh...looking.</p>
        </dd>

    <dt>Sanity falling</dt>
        <dd>
            <div class="placeholder">
                <img src="img/2ieLb3RAblA.png" id="2ieLb3RAblA" />
            </div>

            <div class="close">x</div>
        </dd>

    </dl>

    </div>

    <div id="foot">

    </div>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```